DevExpress and Syncfusion old versions
I have to deal with one old .NET (C#) project and for that action I need DevExpress 10.1.7 and Syncfusion 9.0. It is very hard to find it online, so if someone can help me with that I would be really grateful. I am aware of the fact that this versions are quite old, but still...
I already tried to find it online, but without success.

Assuming you have a valid license,  you can download older versions directly from the DevExpress download manager.
Select your product and then use the drop-down list to find the specific version you require. 

Thank You for your answer. I don't have a licence, and need that old version since I am trying to use old code for practice. Is it possible to download DevExpress 10.1.7 under free trial period?

No, DevExpress does not offer old versions of their trial. You'll need to purchase a new license to access the old version required.

If you have a valid Syncfusion license, you can download the Syncfusion installers by logging into your Syncfusion account using your credentials.
Refer to this UG documentation link for downloading the installer.
https://help.syncfusion.com/common/essential-studio/installation/offline-installer/how-to-download
From the “License & Download” page, please click on “Download Older Versions” as shown in the below image to download the v9.*

Download the required v9.* Syncfusion Essential Studio setup.

An unlock key is required to install the Syncfusion installers. Click on the "Get Unlock Key" option to generate the unlock key. A dialog box will open, and you can choose the required version and generate the unlock key.
How to generate an Unlock key? | Syncfusion


If you have further questions, please create a support ticket at https://support.syncfusion.com/create.
